# Is it necessary to learn semaphores and threading to work with PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading

Is it necessary to learn semaphores and threading in order to work with PHP?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In fact, threading in PHP is a real hassle and not recommended for web scripting anyway since most web servers don't support it (Apache with mod_php cannot fork PHP threads in a reliable manner).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're going to do CLI scripts in PHP (which is a pretty popular task), then no.

If you are going to write PHP scripts that will be run from the command line (not through a webserver), these can be very handy. You might also want to take a look at [`fork()`](http://php.net/fork) and maybe even [`socket_select()`](http://php.net/socket-select) if you get into more complicated stuff.

There's a world of things you can do from the CLI, and multithreading and forking will certainly help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, certainly not for the usual web stuff.